# How to forward wireless packet to ethernet interface in windows?

Tags: network-programming, wireless, packet-capture

How to forward wireless packet to ethernet interface in windows?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us more about the context of what you want to do. Why do you want to forward packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in IP packet forwarding feature of Windows to forward packets from your Wireless NIC to your Wired (ie. Ethernet) NIC.